# Как получить название самого большого разряда числа

Tags: python

Я хочу сделать что-то типо счетчика ютуба - 1500000 должен быть **1.5M** и 150000 = **150К**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы сделал бы так (если в лоб):

```
import math

num = 153400000000000000000

# наименование разрядов
prefixes = ['', 'K', 'M', 'G', 'T']

# определить кол-во разрядов
size = int(math.log10(num)) // 3

# получить часть без учёта разрядов
value = num / 10**(3 * size)

# получить префикс
prefix = prefixes[size] if len(prefixes) > size else " дохулионов"

# если префикса для числа нет - вывести число с максимальным префиксом
#if len(prefixes) > size:
#    prefix = prefixes[size]
#else:
#    size = len(prefixes) - 1
#    value = num / 10**(3 * size)
#    prefix = prefixes[size]
    
# вывести текст
print(f'{value}{prefix}')
```